# Connect to oracle .net core

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following code:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = test;
conn.Open();
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

Why in the earth do It need to load System.Configuration.ConfigurationManger?

Comment: that's cause you are mostly getting the connection string from configuration. Or even if you are not using but still you probably have added a reference to that assembly

Comment: @Rahul: No, I have just hardcoded the connectionstring in the variable "test".

Comment: Which specific line of code is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

others are also discussing a similar issue with .NET core and another library, see here: https://github.com/pusher-community/pusher-websocket-dotnet/issues/34

I would try to add a reference to this other Microsoft assembly or to grab it with Nuget as they suggest to do and then I would test the code again at compile time and at runtime.